# How to solve maven COMPILATION ERROR: package X does not exist?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, spring-tool-suite

I have 3 maven projects:

```
project-A
project-B
project-C
```

The second project (B) requires the dependency for the first project (A). 
The third project (C) requires the dependencies for the first and second project (A, B). 
I have defined these dependencies in the respective projects `pom` files: 
`project-B pom.xml` :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mygroupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-A</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

`project-C pom.xml` :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mygroupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-A</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mygroupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-B</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Everything works OK on `SpringToolSuite`. I have tested the second project (which depends on the first project) and also tested the third project (which depends on both first and second project) and everything works OK from STS.

When I try to execute:
mvn clean install -U -DskipTests=true

it works perfectly well for `project-A` and `project-B`, but for `project-C` I get a:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] MyClassOnProjectC.java:[12,38] package XXX does not exist
[ERROR] MyClassOnProjectC.java:[22,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MyClassOnProjectB
  location: class MyClassOnProjectC
```

Below there are 3 classes extracted from each of the projects:

Project-A: 
User.java

```
package com.neweraed.datamodel;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UserType", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "description",
})
public class User  implements Serializable {    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -876063526825526098L;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Project-B: 
UserOperations.java

```
package com.neweraed.services.midpoint;

import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;

import com.neweraed.datamodel.User;
import com.neweraed.services.midpoint.utils.Constants;
import com.neweraed.services.midpoint.utils.Utils;

@Component
public class UserOperations {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserOperations.class);

    public User getUser(User user) {
        RestOperations restOperations = Utils.createGenericRestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<User> response = null;
        try {
            response = restOperations.exchange(Constants.ENDPOIT_SEARCH_USER, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(Utils.createHeaders()), User.class);

            logger.info("=== RESPONSE ===" + response + " === ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("=== ERROR === " + e.getMessage() + " === ");
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Project-C:
UserService.java

```
package com.neweraed.rest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.neweraed.datamodel.User;
import com.neweraed.services.midpoint.UserOperations;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/users")
public class UserService {


    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        UserOperations userOperations = new UserOperations();
        return userOperations.addUser(user);
    }
}
```

It seems like everything is OK on my pom.xml files. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

According to your premises, `pom.xml` of the project B must be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-A</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And project C doesn't need the dependency with A because it is defined on B

Comment: Yes correct. I tried removing dependency of project-A from pom.xml of project-C and re-executed the command but I get the same error

Comment: The packaging type of A and B is pom?

Comment: No, packaging type of A and B is jar

Comment: Without more details of the projects I'd try to change them to pom and executing the clean install command again

Comment: I tried changing packaging type for projects A and B to pom and re-executed the clean install command again but nothing changed. 
The projects are really simple. Each of the three projects defines the groupId, artifactId, version, packaging and same parent: 
       <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Comment: I solved my problem changing packaging type of my three projects to pom